# It it "normal" that monerod and monero-wallet-gui are very unstable over torsocks?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, tor

I configured a private remote node using the official [docs](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source) (compiled from source at `release-v0.17` on Debian buster).

When I run `monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf`, the node appears to work as expected.

```
$ monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf status
2021-03-18 14:51:16.460 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)
Height: 2319663/2319663 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 2.16 GH/s, v14, 0(out)+0(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 36m 11s
```

When I run `DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf`, running `monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf status` hangs and I see many `We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit...` errors in `/var/log/syslog`.

```
$ DNS_PUBLIC=tcp torsocks monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf
2021-03-18 14:53:01.224 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)
...
2021-03-18 14:53:04.156 I SYNCHRONIZATION started
...
1616079308 ERROR torsocks[5975]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:527)
...

$ monerod --config-file /home/monero-admin/.monero/monerod.conf status
2021-03-18 14:53:12.637 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.1.9-release)
```

I believe something is not working at the `torsocks` level but I don't know how to troubleshoot this further.

On the wallet side, connecting to node over Tor using `torsocks` takes for ever to connect even when the node is working as expected (when not connected though `torsocks`).

```
$ cat .monero/monerod.conf
data-dir=/home/monero-admin/.monero
log-file=/home/monero-admin/.monero/monero.log
log-level=0
p2p-bind-ip=127.0.0.1
no-igd=1
```

I am likely doing something wrong.

Comment: I want to ask you a question. Can we fix the mistake made in the last letter of the address? One of my relatives mistyped the last letter of the address while transferring and their tokens were lost. thanks sercanyoung@icloud.com

Comment: Welcome to Monero! If you have a NEW question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//monero.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](//monero.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.